# Select all rows which match a condition dependent on over rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's assume I have a table T with the columns X, Y, Z where Z is some comparable value
(I have to make it work on a PostgreSQL database but a solution that additionally supports oracle would be even nicer).

What I want to achieve is best described by the following, sadly invalid query:

```
SELECT X, Y, MAX(Z) 
FROM T OVER (PARTITION BY Z) as max_z 
GROUP BY Y 
WHERE Z < z_threshold AND Z = max_z AND X = some_x
```

This is invalid since window function result cannot be accessed in a where clause as I understood from the (PostgreSQL) documentation.

In other words, for each group of rows with the same y-value I want to select the row which has the maximum `Z` in that group.

Currently my solution is to just select all rows where `X = some_x` and `Z < z_threshold` and then "post-process" the data outside of sql, which is not very efficient with large datasets.

Is it possible to achieve this result with plain sql or is there any other more  efficient solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT X, Y, Z, MAX(Z) OVER (PARTITION BY Y) as max_z
      FROM T
     ) t
WHERE z = max_z;
```

If there are duplicates maximuma for a given `y`, this returns all the duplicates.  Often `ROW_NUMBER()` would be used for this purpose, but you started with `MAX()` so this also works.

Note:  In Postgres, I would recommend `DISTINCT ON`:

```
select distinct on (y) t.*
from t
order by y, z desc;
```

Comment: To get all the duplicates when maximum is unique, one would use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`. `ROW_NUMBER()` would not work - it returns different row numbers even in the case of ties.

Answer (score 1):

Row-numbering is usually the easiest and most efficient method:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Y ORDER BY Z DESC) rn
    FROM T
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

You can use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` if you want tied results